# Modles dialog creation without using dialog pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Why second line of code below rises exception

```
StatusDlg statusDlg (CWnd::GetDesktopWindow());
statusDlg.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

and code below goes without problems

```
StatusDlg * statusDlg = new StatusDlg(NULL);
statusDlg->Create(StatusDlg::IDD,CWnd::GetDesktopWindow());
statusDlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW)
```

?

Comment: show us the constructor of statusdlg, does it do a create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the first dosen't create the dialog's underlying window?

Comment: Yes, by adding line statusDlg.Create(StatusDlg::IDD,CWnd::GetDesktopWindow()); everything goes fine. I was expecting that constructor StatusDlg statusDlg (CWnd::GetDesktopWindow()); is responsible to create window

Comment: @user1501700: `MFC` has always used 2-stage construction for `CWnd` derived classes. First stage creates the C++ object and the second stage creates the `HWND` and attaches it to the C++ object.